# How to check the display style of an element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on an asp.net mvc3 application. In the view a have a hidden input field with `type="text"` which is shown under certain conditions. If the conditions are met and the field is shown I want to perform client-side validation if there is text entered.

The HTML rendered for the input when it's hidden is this :

```
<input class="yesNoNotApplicableTextbox" type="text" value="" style="display: none;" name="[14].FieldValue">
```

When the input became visible the HTML changes to this:

```
<input class="yesNoNotApplicableTextbox" type="text" value="" style="" name="[14].FieldValue">
```

In my `.js` file I have this :

```
$("input.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox[type='text'][style='display: none;']")
```

in fact I don't need the field when it's not visible, I just wanted to check if this works and it works indeed. But accordingly to the generated HTML if I check if the input is visible like this:

```
$("input.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox[type='text'][style='']")
```

it's not working.

How can I check if the input field is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only select elements that match the selector and are visible:

```
$("input.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox[type='text']:visible")
```

The difference between `:visible` and `.is(':visible')` is this:

`:visible`
Me: hey jQuery, give me all of the elements that match this selector and that are visible.
jQuery: OK, here are the elements.

`.is(':visible')`
Me: hey jQuery, give me all of the elements that match this selector.
jQuery: here are the elements you requested.
Me: OK, now give me the elements from this list that are visible.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> Description: Selects all elements that are visible.
>
> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox[type='text']:hidden") //hidden ones

$("input.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox[type='text']:visible") //visible ones
```

Comment: Wont's this get only when it's hidden? I need the opposite - to get it if it's visible?

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("input.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox[type='text']").is(':visible')){
    alert("Visible");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you explain me in few words what is the difference between `[type='text']:visible` and yours `[type='text']").is(':visible')` is there any advantage in using this syntax or they are the same in this case?

Comment: @Leron there is no difference at all in term of result

Comment: @roasted Thanks, then I guess I'll stick to the simplier one.

Comment: There's no difference in terms of matched elements (the result), but there may be a performance advantage from using one or the other; that's probably not going to be noticeable enough to warrant special consideration unless you're actually seeing poor performance.

Comment: @Anthony Grist no, that's not the case. Was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
$("input.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox[type='text']:visible")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox[type='text']").is(":visible")
```